# Limit custom taxonomy dropdown by custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, custom-taxonomy

I have 2 custom post types connected to the same custom taxonomy. On a particular page I needed to filter one particular post type using the filter that I created for my custom taxonomy. I was able to get a dropdown of my custom taxonomy using `<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>` but what I noticed was that it listed all the terms for which atleast one of the 2 custom post types had a post linked to it.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: 
1. I have 2 custom post types: Cars and Bikes
2. I have a custom taxonomy (Location)
3. On a specific page, I need to filter the post type Cars using the dropdown that I created for my taxonomy
4. The problem that I'm facing is that the dropdown for my taxonomy Location, lists the locations that even posts from the Bikes post type are also connected to. So for example, if I have posts from the Cars post type connected to USA, UK, Australia and a post from the Bikes post type connected to Brazil, the dropdown for my custom taxonomy lists the 'Brazil' term too even though none of the Cars posts are linked to it.

Is it possible to restrict the dropdown for taxonomies to one custom post type?

Comment: Have you created the same taxonomy for both custom post type? Or are you using the default taxonomy of wordpress?

Comment: Hi Kausha, yes both post types use the same taxonomy to manage locations.

Comment: Are you using the default taxonomy or created the custom taxonomy?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I created a custom taxonomy and both the post types use the same custom taxonomy

Comment: Then you have to use the different taxonomy for different post type otherwise how can you differentiate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on the Wordpress Stackexchange site and got the answer. Linking to it in case anyone else is interested in it:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207655/restrict-taxonomy-dropdown-to-post-type